# Highlight text event d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Not an expert at d3.js, looked around, couldn't find/understand how to achieve this:

```
<p class='my-text'> Hi! this is a paragraph!</p>
```

A user highlights a few words in that paragraph, which fires an event that creates a line from the top-middle part of the highlight and then goes right to a box for a user to comment on.

How does one do this in d3.js? 
Is there a resource that i can take a look at for manipulating text with d3.js?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get the "line" to a comment box to work; you're mixing up HTML content (with text that will wrap from line to line based on window and font size) with SVG drawing elements (which are always absolutely positioned).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  I'm afraid d3 can't do anything unique to make this work out just the way you're imagining, but there are some methods in the standard Javascript API that can help.

The [`.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection) method of the document or window returns the selected text with information about where it is in the document tree as a [selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).  However, note that it doesn't seem to be supported in IE8 or under.

Working from there, and using the [.splitText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text.splitText) method and other basic Javascript functions, it is possible to insert a floating, editable `<div>` element (or an input text) at a point in the selected text.

In this fiddle, I mark the point in the original text that relates to the comment with a red asterisk that shows up when you hover over or edit the comment:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/5sT7t/3/

Key code:

```
function checkSelection(d,i) {
    var sel = document.getSelection();

    if (sel.isCollapsed) return;
      // The selection doesn't have any content,
      // i.e., it's just the cursor location,
      // so don't do anything.

    var commentBox = document.createElement("div");
    var commentMarker = document.createElement("span");
    //create new elements, not currently attached to anything

    d3.select(commentBox)
        .attr("class", "commentBox")
        .datum( sel.toString() ) //save for later reference??
        .text("Comment on \"" + sel.toString() + "\"")
        .attr("contentEditable", "true")
        .on("mouseup", stopEvent)
        .on("keyup", stopEvent); //don't trigger comments within comments!

    d3.select(commentMarker)
       .attr("class", "commentMarker");

    var split = sel.anchorNode.splitText( sel.anchorOffset );
    //split the text node containing the start of the selection
    //into two text nodes, and save the second one

    sel.anchorNode.parentNode.insertBefore(commentMarker, split);  
    sel.anchorNode.parentNode.insertBefore(commentBox, commentMarker);
    //insert the comment marker into the paragraph just before
    //the split point; insert the box just before the marker;
    //order is important, so that the marker's CSS can be 
    //dependent on the box's hover/focus state

    sel.anchorNode = split;
    sel.anchorOffset = 0;
    //shift the selection to only include content after the split
    //(this doesn't actually work...)
}
```

To try to get something closer to what you were asking for, I replaced the asterisk with a long block with a top-border acting as the "line".  However, there's no way to easily set the width of that block to fill the space from an arbitrary point in the text to the comment box on the border, so I had to overshoot and then use a wrapper to hide the overflow.  The height of the line also doesn't match if there are multiple comments, which causes the comment boxes to no longer line up with the line of text to which they're attached.  But it's something you can play around with:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/5sT7t/4/

Comment: Thanks for this amelia! I guessed as much, that it might not be possible with d3, i did something similar to what you have here, essentially, took a row, with about 80 percent width used for the text, and the rest 20 percent just blank. with getSelection and some basic manipulation with ranges, its possible to find the distance from the top of the document to the word/words thats highlighted, once you get the height, its easy to draw a simple border line in the 20 percent area that runs on the side to make a box such thatitsthe same height from top of document, so that appears right alongside!